# WP8 sockets in background

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-voip

I am working on VOIP app. I am using VOIP API. The issue which i am facing is whenever app goes in background all my sockets like SIPSocket and RTPSocket is getting closed. It seems some how i can keep those sockets open while my app goes to background.Let me know if anyone have done to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using the VoIP app from a InProc WinRT component? You need to use it OutProc, or it won't run in the background.

See [VoIP apps for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206983%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and our [ChatterBox VoIP sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b)

The ChatterBox sample also have the necessary tooling for registering OutProc interfaces with your managed app.

Comment: can you send me some link i read about that InProc Winrt component? I know you guyz are using in Chatterbox VOIP Sample but i am having hard time to understand it.

Comment: I don't think we have more documentation than already provided. But I wouldn't recommend making your own VoIP app, unless you have a deep technical understanding of these topics.

Comment: my entire sip stack is in managed code.....can i use that and some how integrate in InProc WinRT component .... or do i have to rewrite the entire code in native code.

Comment: i have created my code the only issue is i am not sure how you are adding InProc WinRT component as my all sip sockets are getting closed when app goes in background.